# Move untracked files into new git repository and preserve directory structure

Tags: git, bash

I made some bad commits with sensitive info to a git repository, `old-project`, which contains large, untracked data and output files. This repo was cloned from an upstream repository, `project`, which doesn't contain the data files. I have cleaned the bad commits from the history of the `project` repo using [`BFG Repo Cleaner`](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/).

Now, I would like to make a new clone, `new-project`, of the cleaned `project` repo, i.e.

```
git clone git://example.com/project new-project
```

and then move the data files from `old-project` to `new-project` and preserve their directory structure.

My initial idea is something along the lines of

```
cd old-project
git ls-files --others --exclude-standard
```

then `mv` the resulting files with `xargs`, but I would like to know if there is a 'proper' way of doing this.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the purpose of your new clone? Would a direct `mv old-project new-project` serve that purpose?

Comment: `old-project` had some bad commits (sensitive data), which I cleaned from the history in `project`, so I want to delete `old-project`.

Comment: Clone to `new-project`, delete everything but the `.git` directory, back up (for safety) and delete `old-project/.git`, `cp -a old-project new-project` then `git reset --hard` in `new-project`? Alternatively look into `rsync` (telling it to only copy files that don't exist in the target (`new-project`)?

Comment: OK, that makes sense. The data files are several hundred GB so I am aiming to use `mv` rather than `cp`. This rules out `rsync` but your first suggestion could work...

Comment: Check out the `--link-dest` option for `rsync`, which will create hard links (`mv` essentially creates a new hard link then removes the original link).

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Are you suggesting I `rsync --link-dest` from `old-project` to `new-project`, only operating on files that aren't present in `new-project`, then delete `old-project`? What effect would this have on the git history in `new-project` (given that I'm trying to avoid copying the history from `old-project`)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `git filter-branch` to go through and perform an operation on each commit, removing files that you no longer need. If you have a repository that is structured `oldstuff/` and `newstuff/` you can run:

```
git filter-branch --subdirectory-filter newstuff -- --all
```

You'll be left with a repository where the tags and branches are rewritten such that only files that appeared in `newstuff/` will exist.

If you want to remove certain file types (say, `*.log`) then you can do a similar command:

```
git filter-branch --tree-filter 'rm -f *.log' -- --all
```

If you have log files in subsequent levels you will need to adjust the command appropriately e.g. with `xargs`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm not sure I understand how this will help me move **untracked** data files from `oldstuff` to `newstuff`. Could you maybe expand a little?

Comment: See the man pages by running `git help filter-branch` for more information. If the data is untracked then it isn't part of the Git repository.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I think I understand what you are doing here. In fact, I already cleaned the bad commits from the upstream repo (`project` in my question). I have updated the question to make this more explicit.